# C# Read Serial Port Data after complete message

Tags: c#, serial-port, port

I want to read a message sent by a chemical analyzer through a serial port. I have written the following code. It reads the bytes received, but there are instances where some bytes are combined and an unexpected set of bytes are received midway the message. Is there any way I can wait till the end of the message and get all bytes?

```
SerialPort com = new SerialPort();
List<byte> thisMessage = new List<byte>();
string status = "";


private void btnOpen_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e){
    btnOpen.Enabled = false;
    btnClose.Enabled = true;
    try
    {
        com.PortName = cmbPort.Text;
        com.BaudRate = Int32.Parse(txtBaudRate.Text);
        com.DataBits = Int32.Parse(txtBitLength.Text);
        com.ReadBufferSize = 100000;
        com.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        com.DtrEnable = true;
        com.RtsEnable = true;
        com.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    com.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(com_DataReceived);
}




private void com_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int bytes = com.BytesToRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
    com.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        if (ContainEnd(buffer))
        {
           status += DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + " Message Received From Analyzer." + Environment.NewLine;
            thisMessage.AddRange(buffer);
            String ts = "";
            foreach (byte b in thisMessage)
            {
                ts += b + " ";
            }
            status += ts + Environment.NewLine;
            thisMessage = new List<byte>();
            status += "End of a Message " + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            thisMessage.AddRange(buffer);
            String ts = "";
            foreach (byte b in buffer)
            {
                ts += b + " ";
            }
            status += DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + " Part of a Message " + ts + Environment.NewLine;
        }

    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

}
```

When I run this code, I get bytes like 5 2 2 194 77 181 48 105 94
Here byte 2s are not expected at this part of the message. There can not be bytes like 194 or 181. So I think there is a mis-read of bytes.

How can I get the correct bytes from serial port ?

Comment: "How can I get the correct bytes from serial port?" When you read from the serial port, the bytes you get are the bytes that were sent, and sometimes there can be garbage data (depending on the hardware).  You're going to have to deal it the data that comes through.

Comment: They are NOT sending byte 2 in the middle of the message. There can not be two number 2 bytes next to each. The analyzer is not sending bytes like 180. So there must be an error in reading bytes, not an error in sending them by the other instrument